# javascript подключается через раз

Tags: javascript, html

Есть сайт со слайдером.
Слайд использует библиотеку SlidesJS. Структура слайдера:

```
<div id="slider">
<div class="slide">
    <div class="slide-img">
        <img src="" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slide">
    <div class="slide-img">
        <img src="" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slide">
    <div class="slide-img">
        <img src="" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slide">
    <div class="slide-img">
        <img src="" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Возникла следующая проблема скрипт отрабатывает через раз - заходим на страницу показывается просто столбик из картинок. Обновляем раз 4-5 и только после этого отрабатывает скрипт и формируется слайдер. Если после этого еще раз обновить страницу, появляется снова столбик из картинок.

Comment: А где и как вы его подключаете?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/index.js"></script>
Прямо перед <div id="slider">

Comment: попробуйте добавить в <head> ... </head>

Comment: ммм, ну я бы наоборот, посоветовал перед закрытием body, т.е.
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/index.js"></script>
</body>

Вообщем суть проблемы в том, что у вас не успевает отстроиться DOM дерево, а код слайдера уже начинает работать.

Comment: поставил в конце - все вроде как заработало, очень странно такой косяк появляется только в опере и фаерфоксе иногда. В хроме же все отлично.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подключай скрипты в конце `body` и запускай инициализацию в `JS`:

```
$( window ).load(function() {
  // Run code
});
```

Инициализация слайдера произойдет сразу после полной загрузки страницы, если страница написана качественно (0-2 секунды для загрузки), то это решение будет оптимальным.

В противном случае, лучшие подключить инициализацию на загрузку в `body`:

```
<body onload="yourFunction();">
  //Some code
</body>
```

Comment: подключил в конце кода и все заработало, благодарю.